# Is an Arduino Uno made in the USA compatible with SunFounder shields?

Tags: arduino-ide, shields

I bought an Arduino Uno from Radio Shack. I was under the impression it was the authentic model made in Italy. I read on Arduino.cc that the USA version is licensed and essentially the same. I then went to Amazon and ordered an RBG shield, and what I thought was the starter kit that is used with the examples on the IDE. I received the package and it is from SunFounder. Will this work with the IDE on the website and the Arduino I have from Radio Shack?

Comment: Generally if the boards are individually functional and the two *mechanically* fit together, they will probably work.  The exception might be some 3.3v non-ATmega boards.   Mechanical issues can include different version of the shield interface with fewer or more pins, special function pin assignments that differ between a normal Arduino vs. a Mega, and the full-size USB connector on official-style boards shorting against the underside of some shields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest official Arduino IDE : [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)

Every Arduino Uno and all the clones are compatible. Some clones have the CH340G usb-serial chip and require an extra driver. If you look very hard, you might find an Arduino Uno board that is not version 'R3' and does not have SDA and SCL near the USB connector, or does not have the polyfuse for USB 5V, or uses an ATmega328 instead of a ATmega328P. There is a chance of maybe 1 in 10,000 that you find a wrong Uno board, and in most cases those are still compatible.

Do you mean the SunFounder RGB Matrix Driver Shield? That should be no problem.

Comment: Yes the RGB Matrix Driver Shield, and thanks for the response.